# C# from read text file to read binary file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, binaryfiles

how do I modify this code to read binary file using BinaryReader?
Example snort's log file?(text and number are include)

```
public string ReadFullFile()
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(this.filename))
    {
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the data you read? Do you want to process it somehow or do you just want the entire content of the file like in code sample provided?

Comment: i want to analysis the packet...so i need read all the content inside the log file..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about snort's log, but binary reader goes something like this:

```
class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
function ReadFullFile(Action<Record> processRecord)
{
    using(var file = new FileStream("whatever.bin"))
    {
        using(var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
        {
            processRecord(new Record
            {
                Id = reader.ReadInt32(),
                Name = reader.ReadString(),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte[] ReadFullFile()
{
    return File.ReadAllBytes(this.FileName);
}
```